# Building 3-8 decoder with two 2-4 decoders and a few additional gates

Tags: decoder

I am trying to build a 3-8 decoder without an enable by using two 2-4 decoders (that also don't have enables), two chips that each contain 4 AND gates, and one chip that contains 4 NOT gates.

I have tried to base my solution on this answer: 
[Design a 3-to-8 Decoder Using Only Three 2-to-4 Decoders](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/132356/design-a-3-to-8-decoder-using-only-three-2-to-4-decoders)

but I have not been able to figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by creating an enable function.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftlFp6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Does this give you any ideas? (Hint, you'll only need a single NOR gate to decode the enables.)

Comment: I'm not quite understanding.
I only want to be using the gates specified and I can't use any enables.

Comment: Half way there, and still NOT getting it enabled?

Comment: @GabeB-David: Think really carefully, he's giving you an implementation of the 3rd bit.

Comment: @GabeB-David - Will it help to tell you that you can use the address msb as an enable?

Comment: @slabetman: Oh! I totally did not see that! Okay now everything is making a lot of sense.
Thank you all very much